# Jquery Clone Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to customize html by JQUERY clone function let say i have a div

```
<div id="my_Div" style="margin-right:14px;"> Name :
                <input type="text" name="file_name[]" id="file_name" class="validate[required]"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp; Choose File :
                <input type="file" name="upload_file[]" id="upload_file" class="validate[required]" onChange="getFileExtension('upload_file');"/> 
              </div>
```

no by clone function

```
$('#my_Div').clone().appendTo("body");
```

i can make as it is clone html but i wanna customize

```
<input type="text" name="file_name[]" id="file_name" class="validate[required]"/>
```

i.e

```
<input type="text" name="file_name[]" id="file_name1" class="validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="file_name[]" id="file_name2" class="validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="file_name[]" id="file_name3" class="validate[required]"/>
```

any help???

Comment: `var clone = $('#my_Div').clone();` edit the html with jquery functions and then append `clone` var to body

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to customize the cloned copy you get back. Although there's not built in way, you can take the logic of what you want to change and put it in a function to be called after like so:

```
clonedElement.attr('id', function () {
 // logic
});
```

More detail can be found here: [jQuery to clone a table with new id, how to write below code collectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752202/jquery-to-clone-a-table-with-new-id-how-to-write-below-code-collectively)

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 1;
var tmp = $('#my_Div').clone();
var inp = tmp.find('#file_name');
inp.attr('id', inp.attr('id')+i);
i++;
tmp.appendTo('body');



I would add class to all inputs, for example class="changeable" and add:    
$('.changeable').on('change', function() {
 //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not do this with or within the clone function, especially not by manipulating html strings. Better do something like this:

```
var c = $('#my_Div').clone().appendTo('body');
var i = c.find("#file_name").attr('id', "file_name0");
for (var i=1; i<3; i++)
    i.clone().appendTo(c).attr('id', "file_name"+i);
```

However, I don't think multiple elements of the same type do need (numbered) ids. A descriptive class name should be enough.