# How to pass records from one view to another view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table of records and a submit button.
How do I pass those records from one view to another view while clicking the Submit Button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a table of records (from where are you getting those records?)

I'm guessing

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ModelTemp = model = new ModelTemp();
    model.listRecord = new List<ModelTempB>();
    return view(model);
}
```

In your view:

```
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.listRecord .Count; x++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.listRecord[x].Someproperty)
            <br/>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.listRecord[x].Someproperty)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In your controller for Post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirmation(ModelTemp model)
{
    //now you can access the list of records
    return view();
}
```

Comment: How to pass list of records from one table to another table?

Comment: what are you trying to do?, you can use jquery to clon a table

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752202/jquery-to-clone-a-table-with-new-id-how-to-write-below-code-collectively

Answer (score -1):

easiest way would be put a hidden input within the form same as submit button, serialize your records to json string on client or server depending on your situation. you can access the form collection and deserialize records from string in other controller.